# Getting grid data to a CSV file

Tags: qgis-3, csv, vector-grid

I have a road shapefile of a selected area of 1km x 1km created in QGIS. I have also been able to create a grid shapefile of 1m x 1m intervals over my area as below: -
[image]

Is there a possibility to get each grid cell's data (i.e, "does this cell contain a road or it is not a road?" kind of data taken from the road shapefile and the area shapefile that is in its background) into a CSV file?

Comment: exporting to an ASCII grid may be a better choice than a CSV file

Answer (score 1):

`Join attributes by location` to attach the road attributes to the grid, then export the grid to CSV.